ODR Violation with static variables and multiple shared libraries in Linux
Say I have the following scenario:
A static library (let's call it DummyStatic.a) that declares and defines the following class:
class DummySingleton {
private:
    static DummySingleton the_instance_;
public:
    DummySingleton& instance() noexcept; // defined in source file
};

So this class declares the_instance_ in the header file inside the DummySingleton class and defines it in the source file.
Everything is good so far, but lets say I have the following setup:
shared_lib_a.so and shared_lib_b.so are both linking statically DummyStatic.a
static_lib_x.a is linking shared_lib_a.so and shared_lib_b.so
DummyExecutable is a executable that link static_lib_x.a (doesn't make any calls to any functions, it's just contains empty int main() {..} )
If I run this setup as I describe above, ASAN will give me ODR violation warnings on the_instance_ variable, and even worse if I declare a
static std::string inside the DummySingleton and define it in the source file, I will get a crash with double-free error.
Now, If I get rid of the static DummySingleton the_instance_ and make it inline (C++ 17 inline) inside the source file
or I define my static inside the source file like so:
DummySingleton.cpp:
static DummySingleton ds{};
DummySingleton& get_ds() {
    return ds;
}

Everything looks fine and ASAN doesn't complain.
I can't understand what is happening here, can someone explain it to me?
Is it becuase each shared library that includes the header with my class definition will try to define the static member, but the second approach (file static) doesn't cause this issue because the variable is internal to the translation unit where it's defined? and it's not exposed in headers and doesn't get replicated across shared libraries ?

Maybe not related to the ASAN errors, but why your DummySingleton& instance() is not static, and how are you planning to obtain an instance of your singleton? Also, why do you need the_instance_ to be a static field of your class? The typical singleton pattern is implemented using lazy-evaluation, and the instance is hidden in the implementation.

"static_lib_x.a is linking shared_lib_a.so and shared_lib_b.so" That's nonsense. Static libraries can't link anything. Please show your source files and build commands in their entirety, without editing out or omitting anything. Every little detail matters.

@pptaszni That is mistake - yes I could have used the "Mayers" singleton pattern, but the point of the question is, why this happening in the first place?

Where is DummySingleton::the_instance_ is defined.

Offtopic: singleton is kind of fools gold.

@MarekR I agree, it kills unit testability. and OP would do well to understand dependency injection  and explicit life cycle managment

@PepijnKramer Well I come across this code in one of our codebases when a customer hit this double-free error. It was even worse than that as there were few static std::strings and std::vectors and would cause double-free and ODR violation. The singleton example was just easier to explain and reproduce.

In the original variant of the code each static library would define the class-static variable and also two pieces of code that invoke that variable's constructor and destructor. These pieces of code run at the time of the library loading and unloading, respectively.
Now because of the way shared libraries work by default, these pieces of code will construct and destruct whatever instance of the variable is loaded first, rather than the instance that sits in the same library.
Here's the process in detail.
Suppose library1.so is loaded first, and its symbols are added to the global symbol table of the executable. The initialisation code of that library wants to initialize the class-static variables of DummySingleton, say if you define an std::string DummySingleton::s. In order to do that, the code resolves DummySingleton::s using the global symbol table, and all is fine.
Now library2.so is loaded. It also wants to initialize DummySingleton::s, and it also goes to the global; symbol table. But it finds DummySingleton::s of library1.so there, because library1.so was loaded first. So library2.so initializes the same variable again, resulting in a memory leak. The instance of DummySingleton::s that lives in library2.so is never seen or touched.
Worse, when the libraries are unloaded, they try to destroy the same instance of DummySingleton::s twice, for the same reason, resulting in a double-free.
Now when you declare the variable file-static or function-static (edit: not file-static), it gets a hidden guard variable which protects it from being initialized twice. The same process with the global table happens again, but this time the initialisation code checks the guard variable first, and if it is set, the second initialisation doesn't happen.
Technically this is still an ODR violation because the function that accesses the static variable is defined twice. But this violation is benign and does not trigger ASAN.

Thanks, so for variable file-static or function-static it's the same as if I had my static variable declared in a class and defined with "inline" keyword in source file, right? It will add a guard which protects from begin initialized or freed twice.

Yes inline variables also get hidden guard variables.

I am aware that function local statics are threadsafely initialized, the ones on file level I think are not.  So for now I would make them all follow the Meyer's singleton approach.
Also to avoid the static initialization fiasco.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I am interested in the documentation, because in all those years I work with C++ I didn't come across that.

@PepijnKramer you are right, file-static variables don't get the same treatment.
